# Custom image on css

Tags: css

I am trying to style my css dropdown box using only css...
First of all my dropdown have the custom html arrow down, i am trying to put an image on my css to take this default arrow down so i can put my own image to it but i have no idea how to do it...

This is my css for the dropdown box:

```
select {
    height:32px;
    line-height:42px;
    width: 88%;
}
```

How can i put my own image to this code? I also tried following tutorial but its no use for me i can't make it work right...

http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

Comment: And HTML ? where it is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial works for me very well.

I created a fiddle for you to understand, but you have to understand what the author want to say.

HTML code

```
<div class="styled-select">
   <select>
      <option>Here is the first option</option>
      <option>The second option</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
.styled-select {
   width: 240px;
   height: 34px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: url('http://cdn.bavotasan.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/down_arrow_select.jpg') no-repeat right #ddd;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.styled-select select {
   background: transparent;
   width: 268px;
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 1;
   border: 0;
   border-radius: 0;
   height: 34px;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zNCBY/

Comment: How do i make it look 88% on width?

Comment: Hey, when i click on the dropdown the select is bigger then the box how do i make it similar to the box?

Comment: please answer me why is the dropdown bigger then the box?

Comment: Let me 10 minutes to find out to your solution

Comment: i already got it :) i just had to edit the second line of the '.styled-select select' thank you very much